# Simple and fast C++ compression library/class

Tags: c++

Is there some simple, easy to use C++ library or just a class for compression?

It should be something easy to use and fast. Compression ration can be worse.

Answer (score 10):

The [miniz](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/) public domain (unlicense.org) library implements most of the zlib API in a single .C source file.

Comment: The code appears to be on github now: https://github.com/richgel999/miniz

Answer (score 3):

lzo is an alternative to zlib, it

> offers pretty fast compression and *extremely* fast decompression." It does not support streaming, as the similar compression library Zlib (http://www.gzip.org/zlib/) does. It's licensed under the GNU General Public License.

However zlib is also a good choice. The advantage of lzo is the emphasis is on the speed of decompression, it is also faster than zlib however zlib provides better compression ratio.

Trade offs :)

Comment: It's good to know about this one, thanks. The license, however, might be another trade off here, as ZLIB is completely free to use in any project.

Comment: zlib offers several levels of compression, to adjust the ratio speed / rate. I think zlib at level 3/4 is about the same as lzo, then performance depends on the data you are compressing...

Answer (score 1):

Consider bzip2 - patent free, reasonable fast compression and de-compression, and fairly easy to implement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2 http://www.bzip.org

Answer (score 0):

[UCL](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/ucl/) is good for high performance decompression.